# google pixel 2 phone rear camera not working suddenly

Tags: google-pixel-2, google-camera

i am using **google-pixel 2** phone since  2017. phone not able to start camera app  and app getting crashed when i tried to open rear camera . **front camera is working fine** .i contacted google support team they said that try to clear app cache and data. i cleared camera app cache,data but no luck. how do i get my phone rear camera to working condition ? pleas help me out to get it working. thanks

Comment: I faced the same problem and I actually used beta versions just to have their latest taste. If you do the same then it's okay because of the bugs and beta versions aren't stable. If nothing helped at all then first try to delete the data from about or secodly you can restore your phone to stable version.

Comment: thanks @SurajitDas . i am also using beta versions . how can i restore to stable version?

Answer (score 0):

> Before downgrade to the stable version of android you've to keepfew
> things in mind.
>
> - **You've to backup your data *(because flashing erase your data permanently)***
> - **You've to download the [stable image](https://developer.android.com/preview/download) file of your device**
> - **You've to download [Android SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio) *(don't have to download Android Studio, Command Line Tools will be enough to get your jobs
>   done)***

Now the process of flashing into stable version will take some time and follow the rules below.

**1. Turn your developers mode on (by clicking the phone's build number
multiple tiles).
2. Enable USB debugging, unlock OEM and then connect your phone with you PC.
3. Unzip the SDK Tools and then open command promt inside that folder.
4. Unzip the image's zip file into the SDK Tools' folder.
5. Unlock your phone's [bootloader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-uq1Wx6RWE), and accept the unlocking by clicking the volume up button of your phone.
6. Go to the fastboot mode and then flash all the image files using "flash-all" command.
7. After successfully flashing to the stable version don't forget to lock the bootloader (if you don't do experimental stuffs then it'll be better to keep the bootloader locked).
8. Set your phone up.**

And now everything will work fine and will be stable after setting up your phone with your credentials.